Command sss_cache -E not working
On Ubuntu 22.04LTS the command:
sudo sss_cache -E not working.
To achieve the same effect, the following commands must be run in series:
sudo systemctl stop sssd; sudo rm -f /var/lib/sss/db/* /var/log/sssd/* ; sudo systemctl start sssd

What is the question? What are you trying to do?

I opened the question here by mistake, ignore it.
I reported the problem as a bug on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Then does it not make sense you remove it?
